# Return true if a condition is met

Tags: go

I have a function

```
func checkIfRouteExists(ctx context.Context, req *compute.RoutesListCall, IP string) bool {
    if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouteList) error {
        for _, route := range page.Items {
            matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(IP , route.DestRange)
            if matched {
                log.Printf("IP %v has matched", IP)

            }
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The function takes in contexts as arguments to connect to GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and an IP. It takes the IP and compares it whether that IP is available in GCP. If a match occurs, I want the whole function to return `true`

If I do something like

```
if matched {
    log.Printf("IP %v has matched", IP)
    return true
}
```

it complains saying

```
Cannot use 'true' (type bool) as type error Type does not implement 'error' as some methods are missing: Error() string
```

If I put `return true` at the end of the function, it basically returns true for everything.

Where exactly can I put the return so that the function only returns true when I have an IP match ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an anonymous function passed as an argument to `req.Pages()`. You can't use a `return` statement inside the function literal to return from the outer function. The inner function has `error` return type, that's why you can't return `bool` from it, only `error`.

One way to handle this would be to declare a local variable outside of the inner function, and inside the inner function assign the value you would want to return from the outer function, so the outer function can do just that: return that value assigned in the inner function. Conveniently this may be the result parameter itself: named return type.

```
func checkIfRouteExists(ctx context.Context, req *compute.RoutesListCall, IP string) (result bool) {
    if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouteList) error {
        for _, route := range page.Items {
            matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(IP , route.DestRange)
            if matched {
                log.Printf("IP %v has matched", IP)
                result = true
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return // This returns what's currently in the result variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable in the outer function and set that from the anonymous function so it knows what to return:

```
func checkIfRouteExists(ctx context.Context, req *compute.RoutesListCall, IP string) bool {
    var matched bool
    if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouteList) error {
        for _, route := range page.Items {
            matched, _ = regexp.MatchString(IP , route.DestRange)
            if matched {
                log.Printf("IP %v has matched", IP)
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
  return matched
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is calling another function and this another function (`func(page *compute.RouteList) error`) returns an error.

You can just check is this error is nil (no error, all good) and returns an error if there is no match :

```
func checkIfRouteExists(ctx context.Context, req *compute.RoutesListCall, IP string) bool {

    hasMatchingError := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouteList) error {
        for _, route := range page.Items {
            matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(IP , route.DestRange)
            if matched {
                log.Printf("IP %v has matched", IP)
                return nil
            }
        }
        return errors.New(`No match found`)
    })

    if hasMatchingError != nil {
        log.Fatal(hasMatchingError)
    }
    return hasMatchingError == nil
}
```